# SQL - updating records and keeping an audit trail of the changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, updates

I have a table in which 2 columns are to be updated based on the existence of records in several other tables. Also, need to use temporary table for this purpose. And, finally am required to keep an audit trail of the changes. Am I on the right path here?

I have tried the following approach:

```
SELECT t1.ref_no, t1.closr_date, t1.ext_key INTO #temp100

FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1
WHERE 
 ( t1.[CLOSR_DATE] IS NULL )
```

.....and some other conditions to fulfil in the same table

```
SELECT ref_no INTO #temp200

FROM  [dbo].[Table2] t2

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table3] t3
ON t3.[RFVAL_NO] = t2.[SCT_NO] )        
WHERE (( t2.[START_DTTM] > GETDATE() OR t2.[START_DTTM] IS NULL ) )
        UNION ALL
SELECT ref_no FROM  [dbo].[Table3] t4
WHERE ( [A_DTTM] > GETDATE() OR [A_DTTM] IS NULL )
        UNION ALL
SELECT ref_no FROM  [dbo].[Table5] t5
WHERE ( [AS_DTTM] > GETDATE() OR [AS_DTTM] IS NULL )
```

.....and so on

/*****Deleting all the records from #temp100 (that match entries in #temp200)*****/

```
DELETE FROM #temp100 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM #temp200 WHERE #temp200.ref_refno = #temp100.ref_refno);
PRINT 'Records from table t1 (that match records in table #temp100 have been deleted!)'
```

/*****Updating records in [dbo].[Table1] that remain in table #t100 *****/

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] t1 
SET [dbo].[t1].[CLOSR_DATE] = CAST('01-JAN-2011' AS DATE), [dbo].[t1].[EXT_KEY] = 'some string' 
WHERE [dbo].[t1].[CLOSR_DATE] IN ( SELECT ref_no FROM #temp100 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table1] t1 ON #temp100.ref_no = t1.[REF_NO] )
PRINT 'Records in table Table1 have been updated!'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? If it's as stated ("Am I on the right path here?"), a correct answer could be "Yes, you're on the right path", or "No, you're not on the right path" with absolutely no other information being provided. Please edit and rephrase, and make it clear exactly what you're asking and what problem you want us to help solve. Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Thank you folks. Have edited the original question.

Comment: why you "have to use" temporary tables ? is this homework ?

Comment: No, its not homework. However, another colleague had tried without it - a big large script with many tables joined and about 500,000 records are output that have to be then updated. It took really a long time for execution of that script and was susceptible to errors being raised which took quite a bit of time to attempt resolution. Therefore, this approach.

Comment: Well, anyone out there has any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use triggers for this task, it'll save you lots of coding. Try this [Adding simple trigger-based auditing to your SQL Server database](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx)